# Is turning objects that perform infite loops into a services a good practice?

Tags: microservices, azure

I was assigned a task to change the communication mechanism between two parties, from `Azure Event Hub` to `Azure Queue` + `Blob Storage`.
On the way, I thought redesigning a bit the components to make it easier to understand what the repo does/what is going on.
We are talking about a `Service Fabric Application`, with a couple of `Service Fabric` services.
The repo currently has objects that perform non-ending loops, manually implementing a type of `ExecuteAsync` method. They do not run formally as services, though.

In my redesign, I wanted to have these "flow" objects (those who performing infite loops in their own tasks) defined as services (SF stateless services). I think this makes things more intuitive, plus making it pretty simple to gain an understanding of what is going on by simply looking at the repo's object structure.

But this adds the need of communicating between these services. I ask, then:

**Assuming doing what I want is a good thing, does this introduce the "overhead" of having to communicate between the services (like, by means of, say, a queue) - in other words - is this overkill ? (Besides the queue (event hub) from where data is actually retrieved in the first place - I will be queueing/dequeuing an additional queue just for the sake of clarity/simplicity?**

In the current code - each SF service has regular objects doing infite loops, being started in distinct tasks - and defined and injected as singletons into the SF service.

I wanted to turn every object that "behaves" like a service (doing infite work) into a real SF service.

---

**[Update 1]**
Or - the best is to have the main class that reads messages from Event Hub/Queue - declaring events to which consumers would subscribe. Does this work good if the event happens to fire while the previous event handler call did not complete? Well, I need to parse/extract the dequeued event hub data - before the other decoupled services start processing, each with its own part of this extracted data. So pub/sub will need to fire 2 events together - each with its own data type for the corresponding service to process.

---

**[Update 2]**
The whole thing can be summarized to:

1. Having things defined as services allow for greater decoupling and easy scalability. So yes, that would be a good idea.
2. With that in mind, the question now is choosing between pub/sub and message queue patterns as a means of communicating between microservices in distributed systems - and there are plenty of articles about it on the web.
3. In case message queues is a considered a good option - then I finally get back to what I jumped and asked plain and simple: is this justified overhead/would this trade-off here be overkill ?

Comment: hard to work out the relationship between these loops and how you are currently doing the communication. I guess the obvious reason to switch to services is so handle crashes, scaling, changes of a single component without affecting the others etc etc

Comment: @Ewan Scaling was one of the additional reasons I thought they should be turned into services, yes. Decoupling, if I could say that (entities are decouples (they are injected as dependencies) but decoupling would be greater/more explicit. I updated the question adding that perhaps the using pub/sub pattern from the events consumer... but does subscribing works well with asynchronous and multiple calls to event handlers ? That certainly requires me to make everything thread safe there...

Comment: what do you see as the difference between mq and pub sub?

Comment: @Ewan: from my understanding pub-sub is more intended to cases where there are a number (plural) of entities interested in responding to the events.  In my case, there is only one consumer for each of the 2 new queues. It can obviously work, just feels queues are more common in such cases.

Comment: I think you need to give some implementation details here.  it sounds like you think pub sub might be implemented differently from a mq? you are leaving everyone guessing at what you really mean